# Implementing TensorFlow Triplet Loss

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, siamese-network

I would like to implement the built in TensorFlow addons version of [triplet loss](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/losses/TripletSemiHardLoss) with a tutorial [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/tutorials/losses_triplet) for a siamese network, however I can't seem to get it quite right. No matter how I wrangle the code another error pops up, currently

```py
TypeError: Could not build a TypeSpec for <KerasTensor: shape=(3, None, 256) dtype=float32 (created by layer 'tf.math.l2_normalize_4')> with type KerasTensor.
```

Note, this is just a token implementation kept simple in order to understand how to implement Triplet Loss. I don't expect the model to actually learn anything.
Code:

```
!pip install -U tensorflow-addons
```

```py
import io
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_addons as tfa
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import fashion_mnist

# Dummy data to pass to the model
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = fashion_mnist.load_data()

train_data = [x_train[:20000],x_train[20000:40000],x_train[40000:]]
train_labels = [y_train[:20000],y_train[20000:40000],y_train[40000:]] 

train_data = tf.convert_to_tensor(train_data)
train_labels = tf.convert_to_tensor(train_labels)
#train_data = np.asarray(train_data)
#train_labels = np.asarray(train_labels)

def create_model(input_shape):
  inp = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=input_shape)
  x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=2, padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=(28,28,1))(inp)
  x = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2)(x)
  x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3)(x)
  x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=2, padding='same', activation='relu')(x)
  x = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2)(x)
  x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3)(x)
  x = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(x)
  x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation=None)(x) # No activation on final dense layer
  #x = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda y: tf.math.l2_normalize(x, axis=1))(x)
  model = tf.keras.Model(inp,x)
  return model

def get_siamese_model(input_shape):
    """
        Model architecture
    """
    
    # Define the tensors for the triplet of input images
    anchor_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(input_shape, name="anchor_input")
    positive_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(input_shape, name="positive_input")
    negative_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(input_shape, name="negative_input")
    
    # Convolutional Neural Network (same from earlier)
    embedding_model = create_model(input_shape)
    
    # Generate the embedding outputs 
    encoded_anchor = embedding_model(anchor_input)
    encoded_positive = embedding_model(positive_input)
    encoded_negative = embedding_model(negative_input)
    
    inputs = [anchor_input, positive_input, negative_input]
    outputs = [encoded_anchor, encoded_positive, encoded_negative]
    #x = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.math.l2_normalize(outputs, axis=1))(outputs)
    
    # Connect the inputs with the outputs
    siamese_triplet = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs,outputs=outputs)
    
    # return the model
    return embedding_model, siamese_triplet

emb_mod, model = get_siamese_model([28,28,1])

# Compile the model
model.compile(
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.001),
    loss=tfa.losses.TripletSemiHardLoss())

# Train the network
#train_dataset = tf.convert_to_tensor(train_dataset)
history = model.fit(
    train_data,
    epochs=5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what exactly you are trying to do, but you also have to incorporate your labels into your training dataset when using the `tfa.losses.TripletSemiHardLoss()`. Here is a working example:

```py
import io
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_addons as tfa
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import fashion_mnist

# Dummy data to pass to the model
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = fashion_mnist.load_data()

train_data = tf.data.Dataset.zip((tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(x_train[:20000]),
                     tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(x_train[20000:40000]),
                     tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(x_train[40000:])))
train_labels = tf.data.Dataset.zip((tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(y_train[:20000]),
                     tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(y_train[20000:40000]),
                     tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(y_train[40000:])))

dataset =  tf.data.Dataset.zip((train_data, train_labels)).batch(32)                
def create_model(input_shape):
  inp = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=input_shape)
  x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=2, padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=(28,28,1))(inp)
  x = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2)(x)
  x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3)(x)
  x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=2, padding='same', activation='relu')(x)
  x = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2)(x)
  x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3)(x)
  x = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(x)
  x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation=None)(x) # No activation on final dense layer
  #x = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda y: tf.math.l2_normalize(x, axis=1))(x)
  model = tf.keras.Model(inp,x)
  return model

def get_siamese_model(input_shape):
    """
        Model architecture
    """
    
    # Define the tensors for the triplet of input images
    anchor_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(input_shape, name="anchor_input")
    positive_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(input_shape, name="positive_input")
    negative_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(input_shape, name="negative_input")
    
    # Convolutional Neural Network (same from earlier)
    embedding_model = create_model(input_shape)
    
    # Generate the embedding outputs 
    encoded_anchor = embedding_model(anchor_input)
    encoded_positive = embedding_model(positive_input)
    encoded_negative = embedding_model(negative_input)
    
    inputs = [anchor_input, positive_input, negative_input]
    outputs = [encoded_anchor, encoded_positive, encoded_negative]
    #x = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.math.l2_normalize(outputs, axis=1))(outputs)
    
    # Connect the inputs with the outputs
    siamese_triplet = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs,outputs=outputs)
    
    # return the model
    return embedding_model, siamese_triplet

emb_mod, model = get_siamese_model([28,28,1])

# Compile the model
model.compile(
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.001),
    loss=tfa.losses.TripletSemiHardLoss())

# Train the network
history = model.fit(
    dataset,
    epochs=1)
```

```
625/625 [==============================] - 76s 120ms/step - loss: 0.1354 - model_79_loss: 0.0572 - model_79_1_loss: 0.0453 - model_79_2_loss: 0.0330
```

Comment: Thank you! I apologize if the question was unclear, I just had a feeling of fumbling in the dark and wasn't entirely sure what I was doing myself. In essence I was unsure how to implement the tfa.losses.TripletSemiHardLoss() (Are the Lambda layers necessary? Were the labels needed for training or not?) for a siamese network and might've further lost some clarity by posting a token problem instead of my actual code.   

Nevertheless, following your implementation seems to have solved most of my issues, though the model doesn't perform as well as I'd hoped, but that's a topic for another time.

Comment: Do you know why are 4 loss values reported and what do they mean? (loss, model_loss, model_1_loss and model_2_loss)

Comment: Positive Pair Loss, Negative Pair Loss, Semi-Hard Margin, Triplet Margin Loss. See https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/tutorials/losses_triplet